# How to tell WebStorm to only preview file by single click, not create a tab?

Tags: webstorm

By default, clicking on file name in Project View panel will create new editor tab in WebStorm, which is annoying.

At the same time in Sublime only double click on file name will create it.

How can I achieve the same behaviour in WebStorm?

Comment: *"click on file name will create a tag"* Could you please clarify what do you mean by "tag" here (screenshots are welcome)? I assume you are talking about editor tabs ... but I better ask...

Comment: yes, i mean editor tab, and sorry , i already change the content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please disable **Autoscroll to Source** option in Project View settings (under cog icon .. or via right click on window label/title)

[image]

Comment: This is only half the answer :)
You cannot preview, you can only open on click or not.

Comment: @SebastianThomas There is no Preview as in SublimeText. Although at some short period of time (few weeks) it was present but then removed again. The ticket is till open and no movement is seen: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130918 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124569 . The best "Preview" I can offer is to invoke `View | Quick Definition` while in Project View (or other places -- lots of actions work even in drop-down menus etc) -- not ideal by any means but the best from what I can think right now. Plus .. the original Question was about single vs double click...